# iPhone viewport -- width not displaying correctly

Tags: iphone, mobile, viewport

My test WordPress site is at:  www.incitepartners.com/news/

This is a 1000px fixed width site, the CSS is:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 30px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

and the viewport metatag is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000, user-scalable=yes" />
```

The only way I can get the width of the site to accurately display on an iPhone 4 is if I add

```
initial-scale=selfrender
```

But then that shrinks and centers EVERYTHING height AND width...

OR, I can do

```
"initial-scale = .3"
```

and that makes the site approximately display the correct width.

also, there is NO change to the iPhone display if I change the content to content=device-width...  no matter if I specify 1000 or specify device-width... nothing changes.

what am i missing?  this is driving me crazy.

Comment: The `content=device-width` is invalid, you need to use 'width=device-width'. But what do you mean under "to accurately display on an iPhone 4"?

Comment: right...sorry, I meant width=device-width.

Comment: I mean 'accurately display' = to display the full 1000px width of the website in the iPhone browser.  right now it only give me 480px wide.  no matter if I specific content="1000" or "content="width=device-width"... i both cases the site on the iPhone displays 480px wide.

Comment: Again, just to clarify, you want to display website in 1x zoom, so it will looks like on desktop and user will have to scroll left-right in order to see all the 1000px of your website, right? Or you want to show all 1000px website in 480px of the device, i.e. website will be zoomed out in order to fit 480px. Thanks.

Comment: I want to show all 1000px with no scrolling

Comment: to clarify: by setting the content="width=1000" the expected result is that the iPhone browser would zoom the site to 1000px wide and i'd be able to see all content left-to-right.  but this doesn't happen.  instead, the iPhone browser ONLY displays 480px wide.

Comment: well, then width=device-width should work, take a look on the explanation here: http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html

Comment: it SHOULD work.  you're right.  but it doesn't.  if I specify width=device-width the site still displays at only 480px.   what i'm doing for the time being... until I can figure out a solution... is to specify width=device-width, initial-scale=0.3, maximum-scale=2 and that seems to look ok.

Comment: look into `target-devicedpi` should be a little more useful

Comment: @Val isn't that just for Android? He's talking about iPhone 4